# Performance test for salesforce

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, salesforce

I am working on salesforce UI’s.

How can I ensure that whatever UI’s created are able to handle a load.

Do I need to do performance testing?

Please suggest tools , process so that 500 user load / performance testing if any?

Comment: *Do I need to do performance testing?* Yes. Unless you can convince your users to do it for you. *Please suggest tools* Sorry that's explicitly off-topic. *process so that 500 user load / performance testing if any?* Well, first get 500 users who are willing to do it for you; or look into tools for performance testing. jmeter is probably an excellent choice.

Answer (score 0):

Tool choice depends on many factors, i.e.

- ability to integrate flawlessly into your existing [SDLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle) (i.e. if you have Java stack a Python-based tool would be an "alien)
- support of all required use cases (nearly all load testing tools are suitable for web applications testing, however when it comes to more "exotic" tasks like communicating with database, [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), handle [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) requests, etc.) the choice might be less wide
- bugdet (there are some proprietary solutions which cost millions of coins and free/open source options)
- skills (the tool might require coding skills which you and your team may or may not have)

You can find quite a list for instance here: http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview

Given you have `java` tag I would recommend to stick to one of the following:

- [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](https://gatling.io/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) article which highlights main features of the above tools followed by comparison matrix, sample scripts, reports, etc., hopefully it will help you to choose the right option.